# sound card not recognized in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

My inbuilt soundcard was not working well(no bass sound,voice screeching)

Testing:
Speaker:working well with mobile devices
Headphones:screeching sound
Before I had Windows 7 : Got the screeching so thought of trying with ubuntu

so technically I thought it would be a problem of the soundcard so bought a new one (Maestro3i ESS technologies 1998)

Tried with ubuntu 9.10,10.04,12.04 : internal sound card detected , Additional sound card not detected

In Ubuntu 10.04 at the start it was showing the sound card after sometime it was gone still undetected .

Gone through Google : tried alsamixer nothing worked

Please help.!!!

Edit 1:

running code:lspci -knn | grep Audio -A2

```
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:27d8] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:d605]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
--
04:04.0 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: ESS Technology ES1983S Maestro-3i PCI Audio Accelerator [125d:199a]
    Subsystem: ESS Technology Device [125d:1998]
    Kernel modules: snd-maestro3
```

Edit 2 : aplay -l

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
    card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC883 Analog [ALC883 Analog]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Edit 3 :
I have upgraded the OS to 14.04 LTS . Now my sound card is detected but No Sound

Tried aplay -l

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
    card 0: PCI [ESS Maestro3 PCI], device 0: Maestro3 [Maestro3]
      Subdevices: 2/2
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
      Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
    card 1: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC883 Analog [ALC883 Analog]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I tried this tutorial from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingGuide

but i got error during

```
    DRIVER=`lspci -ks SLOTID | grep "Kernel modules:" | awk -F: '{print $2}' | sed 's/ *//g'`; modprobe $DRIVER && echo "$DRIVER" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

ERROR is

```
    modprobe: ERROR: missing parameters. See -h.
```

In alsamixer : default

there is no master control volume in additional soundcard. but master volume is in inbuilt soundcard .Please Help

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Audio -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Hi pilot6 i have added the output .